# Special euro characters

Tags: r, regex, euro

I have a string that seems to contain a special `€` character :

```
my_str                                   # [1] "0€ de frais de courtage"
my_str == "0€ de frais de courtage"      # [1] FALSE
gsub("€","X",my_str)                     # [1] "0€ de frais de courtage"
gsub("€","X","0€ de frais de courtage")  # [1] "0X de frais de courtage"
```

I would like to replace it by the standard `€` character i.e. the one I can type with `Alt-gr + E`.

These strings come from file names I got with `list.files`

How can I do this ?

EDIT:

```
utf8ToInt(my_str)
# [1]   48 8364   32  100  101   32  102  114   97  105  115   32  100  101   32   99  111  117  114  116   97  103  101
utf8ToInt(stringi::stri_enc_toutf8("0€ de frais de courtage"))
# [1]  48 128  32 100 101  32 102 114  97 105 115  32 100 101  32  99 111 117 114 116  97 103 101
```

Comment: I m confused `Alt Gr + E` opens `Edit`. Also why is `gsub("€","X",my_str)` and `gsub("€","X","0€ de frais de courtage")` give different result? and what is `X`?

Comment: On my keyboard I get a `€` sign with `Alt gr + E` but that may be only the case in Europe. `"X"` is just a random character to show what's wrong, and why it doesn't give the same result is exactly what I'm wondering :). Is it clearer ?

Comment: When I copy paste your `my_str == "0€ de frais de courtage"` line I get the same character than I would by using AltGR+E on my azerty keyboard : U+20AC. The difference might have been lost when posting to stackoverflow, you should try posting another representation (unicode as I did, or even raw HEX)

Comment: Yes the different is lost by copy/paste but I have trouble accessing the "real string", see my edit though, as I feel I'm getting closer

Comment: How can I represent the string in other ways ?

Comment: This is fine ! Your first string is in CP1252, where 128 is `€` 's index in the character table. So the `€` you've got is the real deal, just in a different encoding. Regex won't help there, and I don't know the first thing about R so you'll have to find out by yourself how to re-encode to another encoding :) You should probably delete your answer btw, while it improves the explanation of your problem there are quite strict guidelines against clarifications as answers (you should instead edit your question further) and it might attract downvotes.

Comment: It is a real answer, and I'm quite sure it will save a life or two in the future, so I'll leave it there. But thanks, I'll change the wording to avoid confusion

Comment: Just read your answer a second time and noticed you wanted to go from `8364` to `128`, or as we now know from unicode to CP1252 ; I suggest the opposite, since unicode is both more portable and able to represent more different characters than CP1252

Comment: And yes I agree now that this is an answer to your problem :) I can't edit my previous comment anymore and it contains valuable information, so I guess I'll leave it as is. I'm still confused about how you could change the encoding of a single character in a string with regex, but I don't know R so that might explain my confusion. I just hope you haven't ended up with a disgraceful hybrid between UTF-8 and CP1252 string

Comment: Actually as I remember (it's old code that I'm tidying), characters are read as `8364` by `list.files` because the files were named like this for some reason, but when calling the function to read them (`grDevices::pdf`), it crashes unless it's converted to `128`. and as `128` is the one I have on my keyboard I'd rather stick to this one anyway.

Comment: The keyboard doesn't have character representations, it all depend on the file it ends up in. If you're not convinced use an editor like Notepad++ capable of setting the file's encoding, write two files containing `€` in UTF-8 without BOM and in CP1252 and you'll find the two different representations of the character as a result while having pressed the exact same key :)

Comment: Your point about interface with existing code or software is much more important than the benefits of using UTF-8 though, so I'd stay with your solution ; just keep in mind next time you encouter a problem with characters that maybe UTF-8 could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

The strings appear identical but the `€` character is different.

In my EDIT at the bottom of the post we see that the code for the regular `€` is `128` while the code for the troublesome `€` is `8364`.

and sure enough:

```
gsub(intToUtf8(8364),"X",my_str)  # [1] "0X de frais de courtage"
```

So the solution I was looking for is:

```
gsub(intToUtf8(8364),"€",my_str)
```

It replaces the "wrong" `€` character with a "regular" `128` `azerty alt gr + E` `€` symbol.